# How do I wait for a listener to run before continuing execution

Tags: android, firebase

I want to perform a query with a token and I want the token to be retrieved from listener.

I created a variable for the token and set it to a default value.

When I run the code, it uses the default value to query the database. I want to use the value of the listener to query the database.

I am new to Coroutines and I have tried runBlocking to no avail.

Thank you very much in advance

```
private fun getTokenFromUser(): String {
var token = ""

        val mUser: FirebaseUser? = firebaseAuth.currentUser
        val userToken = mUser?.getIdToken(true)
            userToken?.addOnSuccessListener {
                token = it.token!! //the value here is actually set
            }

//I want this token to be the actual value not default
return token
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it thanks to this post [How to return a variable from a listener method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554547/how-to-return-a-variable-from-a-listener-method). After creating the listener and setting up methods:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
      getTokenFromUser(object : OnTaskCompleted{ //passed interface as a parameter
                  override fun onSuccess(token: String) :String{ 
                      Log.e(TAG, "User Token is " + token
                      bearer = token //set it to a global variable
                      return token 
                  }
              }
              )}
```

Hope it helps anyone that needs it.